# Match address rule in sshd_config, , difference between localhost, 127.0.0.1 and [::1]

Tags: ssh, ipv6, ssh-tunnel, localhost

I would like to understand why these three rules in `sshd_config` behave differently :

```
Match host localhost 
   PasswordAuthentication yes
Match address 127.0.0.1
   PasswordAuthentication yes
Match address ::1
   PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Assume one of these rules is set on machine A and there is also another machine B which can locally ssh to A through one of these 3 tunnels :

```
A$ ssh B -R2222:localhost:22 
A$ ssh B -R2222:127.0.0.1:22
A$ ssh B -R2222:[::1]:22
```

To test on machine A, I use :

```
A$ ssh localhost
A$ ssh 127.0.0.1
A$ ssh ::1
```

And  for each tunnel setting I test on B:

```
B$ ssh -p2222 localhost
B$ ssh -p2222 127.0.0.1
B$ ssh -p2222 ::1
```

(only one tunnel is active at the same time)

If it asks for password there is a match, else there is no match. There are 3*(3+3*3)=36 tests. For each 3 different Match rules there are 3 tests on A and 3 tests on B for each 3 different tunnels. Aka 12 tests for each rule.

Results:

For `Match host localhost` there are 12/12 matches (always asks for password).

For `Match address 127.0.0.1` there are 4/12 matches : 1/3 match for machine A with `A$ ssh 127.0.0.1` and 3/3 matches for machine B when tunnel is set by `A$ ssh B -R2222:127.0.0.1:22`

For `Match address ::1` there are 8/12 matches, aka 4 fails : 1/3 fail for A with `A$ ssh 127.0.0.1` and 3/3 fails for B when tunnel is set by `A$ ssh B -R2222:127.0.0.1:22`

Obviously with rule `Match address 127.0.0.1,::1` all combinations will be matched.

However I don't understand how this works, especially why address `localhost` is matched by rule `::1` and not by rule `127.0.0.1`, and why address `127.0.0.1` (resp. `::1`) can be matched by rule `::1` (resp. `127.0.0.1`) only remotely and not locally ?

Comment: You know that `Match Address` is supposed to be used for addresses and `Match host` is used for hostnames right?

Comment: Anyway to understand what is going on, I think you may need to put the server into debug mode.  Specifically `sshd -ddd`.  With that set I would be curious to see what gets logged from the (servconf.c#L986) line.  Anyway.  Here are some links to the related code that might give you some help.   https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/servconf.c#L986
 https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/servconf.c#L1045
 https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/addrmatch.c#L377

Comment: @Zoredache you are right I should had use `Match host localhost`, I updated my question.